# Display form options based on a match from another tables

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, forms, match

I have a book assignment form where the user will select a students reading level and all the available 'book names' from the level will be displayed - I have this part working using JavaScript.

What I would like the form to do is, when displaying all available books, display results based on if a students 'reading interests' match the 'book genre'.

The tables I have:

```
Student:
Reading_level
Reading_Interests

Book:
Book_level
Book Name
Book_genre
```

So far the statement is:

```
SELECT * FROM book INNER JOIN student WHERE book.genre LIKE student.reading_interest
```

These tables are not joined in anyway, I'm not sure how to implement this statement. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is this data stored? If your Student table really only has those two columns I can't see how it's useful; how do you differentiate students? If it has more columns, show us what they are. Also show us an example of your data. Is Reading_interests a comma separated string? It should probably be a separate table with a foreign key back to Student, so each individual genre of interest is a separate entry.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist they are indicating the same thing and i've done this part. I would like to do next is display the books based on if the 'book_genre' and the students 'reading_interests' are a match. Example, if the student has set their interests as sports - the books with sport genre will be displayed.

Comment: Yeah, I originally misread the question, deleted that comment now because it's not relevant. My new comment addresses what you're actually asking about.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist this is what I'm trying to do: SELECT * FROM book INNER JOIN student ON book.genre LIKE ('%' + student.reading_interest + '%'). But it doesn't seem to work and yes the reading interests are comma separated. It would be better to have a separate tables, I will look into it. Thank you